# Canonicalize FQDN (domain name) in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql

I need to canonicalize the domain name (FQDN) in Hive.

Specifically, I want to:

1. Strip the leading all-digit parts (maybe with `pub`): `123.pub456.678.example.com` -> `example.com`
2. Strip the trailing port number (don't ask how it got there): `example.com:80` -> `example.com`

So far I came up with

```
regexp_replace(domain, '^((pub)?[0-9]+\\.)*|:[0-9]+$', '') as canonical
```

which appears to do what I expect it to.

However, sometimes it strips a little bit more than I want to:

1. `990.ro` -> `ro`
2. `411.com` -> `com`
3. `988.com.my` -> `com.my`
4. `10.6.10.140:8827` -> `140`

I don't care much about the last case (I would actually gladly discard all IP addresses en masse), but I would rather not lose valid domains (the first 3 cases above).